# Segmentation Fault while using long long int

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault

I was solving [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/crush/problem) question. I wrote the code and received wrong answer for 10 test cases and correct for 6. I checked the constraints and since they are beyond the range of *int* therefore I replaced *int* by *long long int*. 9 test cases passed but the other 7 are showing segmentation fault now.

What can be the reason for this?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long long int n,m; 
    cin>>n>>m; 
    long long int arr[n]={0}; 
    long long int a,b,k; 
    long long int maxi=0;

    while(m--)
    {
        cin>>a>>b>>k;

        for(long long int i=a-1; i<b; i++)
        {
            arr[i]+=k;
        }
    }

    for(long long int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(maxi<arr[i]){maxi=arr[i];}
    }

    cout<<maxi;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `n`? You might be getting stack overflow due to allocating huge array on stack.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but tell me if this line is readable: `if(maxi<arr[i]){maxi=arr[i];}`.

Answer (score 2):

Main problem is

```cpp
long long int arr[n]={0};
```

That's not valid standard C++, and if the array is too large, it won't fit on the stack, you need to dynamically allocate your array, preferably use `std::vector` for it, like so

```cpp
std::vector<long long int> arr{};
arr.resize(n);
```

Other then that, you should probably check if every array access is inside bounds.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with dynamic allocation

```
long long int *arr = new long long int[n];
```

don't forget to free up memory when you are done

```
delete []arr;
```